# CSS background image and box width (%)

Tags: html, css, background-image

My layout uses percent values in the boxes. For example:

```
h2#news {
    background: url('../images/news-background.jpg');
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    width: 90%;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

It's ok, but when layout increases, background images repeat... look at this image: http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/3503/cssbgandpercent.jpg

Is there a way to background image follow the size of the box?
Thank you.

Comment: As in you want it to stretch and pixelate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `no-repeat` to the background to make it stop early.

You can add the CSS3 property [`background-size: auto 100%;`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm) to stretch the background to fit.
You should also add `-moz-background-size` and `-webkit-background-size`, with the same value.

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that `background-size` doesn't work in IE, so if you need to support IE, you will need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: @Spudley: Such as `AlphaImageLoader(sizeMode="scale")`

Comment: You can do this in IE by adding `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');`